# Searching for elements in a python list

Tags: python, list

Searching for elements in a python list and then accessing particular values

```
Mylist = [('A',3,['x','y','z']),('B',2,['m','n'])]  

Variable = 'A'  

i = Mylist.index(Variable)  
print i
```

For example I would like to check if is Variable is present and access its elements like
 is present then access each of sublist elements one by one

For instance in the above example I would like to check if 'A' is present and if yes then
get access to its individual sublist elements like 'x' , 'y' and 'z'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't found the Python dict yet.  Perhaps you mean:

```
mydict = {}
mydict['A'] = {'count': 3, 'letters': ['x','y','z']}
mydict['B'] = {'count': 2, 'letters': ['m','n']}
```

`mydict` is a dictionary that itself contains dictionaries.

You can then look them up with:

```
val = mydict['A']
print val['letters']
```

Of course, there's little point in storing 'count' since you can just use `len()` if you need to. You could do it like so:

```
mydict = {'A': ['x','y','z'], 'B': ['m','n']}
print mydict['A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a dictionary...

```
myDict = dict([('A',3,['x','y','z']),('B',2,['m','n'])])
if 'A' in myDict:
    val = myDict['A']
```

Comment: ok but can't I search a list ? also for me the order of individual elements in my example for 'A' I want x,y and z to be printed in order

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a dict is really the appropriate data type to use when you need to index things by arbitrary data types (like strings). With nested sequences, there's no guarantee that your 'index' (the 'A' and 'B' in this case) will be unique, and some extra contortion is needed to look up values. Also as others have said, the ['x', 'y', 'z'] part *will* remain in order, regardless of whether it's a list-in-a-tuple-in-a-list, or a list-in-a-dict.

That said, the easiest way I can think of to find the tuple you want without using a dict is:

```
indices = zip(*Mylist)[0]   # ('A', 'B')
index = indices.index('A')  # 0
result = Mylist[index]      # ('A', 3, ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

To get at the sublist, use its index:

```
sublist = result[2]
```

or unpack it:

```
lookup, length, sublist = result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mylist = [('A',3,['x','y','z']),('B',2,['m','n']),
          ('C',5,['r','p','u']),('A',10,['k','X']),
          ('E',8,['f','g','h','j'])]

for i,(a,b,c) in enumerate(Mylist):
    if a=='A':
        print i,c
```

result

```
0 ['x', 'y', 'z']
3 ['k', 'X']
```